# Attribute of custom module not available in terraform

Tags: terraform

I have created locally a custom module that just replicates the [vault_identity_entity](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/vault/latest/docs/resources/identity_entity) official module.

Here it is more or less

```
resource "vault_identity_entity" "this" {
  name              = var.name
  policies          = var.policies
  metadata          = var.metadata
  disabled          = var.disabled
  external_policies = var.external_policies
}
```

In the corresponding `outputs.tf` file, I have this

```
output "entity" {
  description = "The entity created"
  value       = vault_identity_entity.this
}
```

I am now trying to retrieve its `id` [attribute](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/vault/latest/docs/resources/identity_entity#id) as follows

```
module "identities_memberships" {

  source   = "../../../../path/to/identity_group_member_entity_ids"
  for_each = {
    for item in local.memberships: item.member_email => {
      group = item.group
    }
 }

  member_entity_ids = [module.identity_entities[each.key].id]
  group_id          = module.identity_groups[each.value.group].id

}
```

This fails as follows:

```
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on main.tf line 101, in module "identities_memberships":
│  101:   member_entity_ids = module.identity_entities[each.key].id
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.key is a string
│     │ module.identity_entities is a map of object
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "id".
```

The vaule of `local_memberships` as printed when I set it in the `outputs`

```
  + local_memberships = [
      + {
          + group_name   = "admins"
          + member_email = "john@gmail.com.com"
        },
      + {
          + group_name   = "admins"
          + member_email = "maria@gmail.com"
        },
      + {
          + group_name   = "operators"
          + member_email = "maria@gmail.com.com"
        },
      + {
          + group_name   = "viewers"
          + member_email = "adam@gmail.com.com"
        },
    ]
```

and the `module.identity_identities` is the instantiation of the above module

```
module "identity_entities" {

  source   = "../../../../path/to/identity_entity"
  for_each = local.member_groups

  name = each.key
  depends_on = [
    module.identity_groups
  ]
}
```

where `local.member_groups`:

```
+ local_member_groups = {
  + "adam@gmail.com.com" = [
      + "viewers",
    ]
  + "john@gmail.com.com"    = [
      + "admins",
    ]
  + "maria@gmail.com"            = [
      + "admins",
    ]
  + "maria@gmail.com.com"        = [
      + "operators",
    ]
}
```

Why can't I access the `id` attribute? What am I missing?

If I comment out the section that produces the error, the plan shows me it will create for example (among others) this:

```
  # module.identity_entities["john@gmail.com"].vault_identity_entity.this will be created
  + resource "vault_identity_entity" "this" {
      + disabled          = false
      + external_policies = false
      + id                = (known after apply)
      + name              = "john@gmail.com"
    }
```

However when also hardcoding values as follows

```
module "identities_memberships" {

  source = "../../../../modules-terraform/vault/identity_group_member_entity_ids"
  for_each = {
    for item in local.memberships : item.member_email => {
      group = item.group
    }
  }

  member_entity_ids = [module.identity_entities["john@gmail.com"].id]
  group_id          = module.identity_groups["admins"].id

  depends_on = [
    module.identity_entities
  ]
}
```

same error, (now for the other module as well)

```
│
│   on main.tf line 101, in module "identities_memberships":
│  101:   member_entity_ids = [module.identity_entities["john@gmail.com"].id]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.identity_entities["john@gmail.com"] is a object
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "id".
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on main.tf line 102, in module "identities_memberships":
│  102:   group_id          = module.identity_groups["admins"].id
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.identity_groups["admins"] is a object
│
```

Comment: Without seeing the module declaration, the namespace for the output appears incorrect, but the correct namespace cannot be completely determined without more information.

Comment: Can you pls elaborate on this namespace issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly are `local.memberships` and `module.identity_entities`?

Comment: I have also provided an update with a test with hardcoded values

Comment: What are the outputs of `module.identity_entities` module?

Comment: @Marcin, I had to explicitly provide the output as you can see in my answer. Not sure why the entire resource instance output was not enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access `id` of the `entity`, you have to:

```
module.identity_entities["john@gmail.com"].entity.id
```